# Agda: separate declaration from definition

Tags: agda

I'm proving stuff in Agda, and some of my files are starting to get a bit long and cluttered (even after I refactored into smaller modules). Is it possible to have two files, one of which contains type signatures of theorems only, and another which contains those theorems and proofs? I looked at the [abstract](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/abstract-definitions.html) keyword, but that doesn't quite seem to do the right thing.

Of course, I can put all the type signatures at the top of the file, and have all the proofs at the bottom of the file; but it seems cleaner if I could have the statements in a file to themselves.

Comment: Abstract definitions just behave as postulates to usually improve type-checking speed. You can just have all proofs in one file and add again the signatures in another file and set the proof to the proof synonym. This way you'll have one liner proofs. You can't skip the definition of a function in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give names to the types of your lemmas. E.g. in file `Statement.agda`:

```
module Statement where

open import Agda.Builtin.Nat
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

+-sym : Set
+-sym = ∀ m n → m + n ≡ n + m
```

And in file `Proof.agda`:

```
module Proof where

open import Agda.Builtin.Nat
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality
import Statement

+-sym : Statement.+-sym
+-sym m n = {!!}
```

In case your definition is level-polymorphic, Agda unfortunately doesn't have a (surface) name for types of the form `∀ {ℓ : Level} → ...`. You will have to take the levels as arguments in `Statement` and quantify over them universally when using the statement in `Proof`. This would give you something like this:

In `Statement.agda`:

```
open import Agda.Primitive

data ⊥ : Set where

⊥-elim : (ℓ : Level) → Set (lsuc ℓ)
⊥-elim ℓ = ∀ {A : Set ℓ} → ⊥ → A
```

In `Proof.agda`:

```
⊥-elim : ∀ {ℓ} → Statement.⊥-elim ℓ
⊥-elim = {!!}
```

Comment: An answer which reveals that I don't yet grok that types and values are exactly the same!

Comment: How does this work with universe polymorphism? My statement of "ex falso quodlibet" is `exFalso : {n : _} {A : Set n} -> False -> A`, where `False` is defined as a type with no constructors. Then the type of this type would presumably have to be something that contains all of `Level`, but as I understand it, the universe hierarchy is only $\omega$ deep.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I had started writing something about level polymorphism but dropped it because I thought it would just be confusing. I've edited the post to add an answer. Note however that only *first order* level polyorphism is supported by this approach.